# Copy attachment from Gmail to drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api, gmail

I developed a code to take attachement on email in google drive.
Everything is ok except when I have the same name of file, I would like to update the version and keep the link in drive than create a new file with the same name.

I don't have idea for that.

Regards

Gautier

Comment: @ whoever vote closed this question.  This question is not to board its a single issue well explained.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update You need to enable Advanced Google services in apps script

Answer (score 0):

This is how the Google drive API works.   When you upload a file it uploads the file you tell it to.  It does not check that the name of the file is unique.

If you want to do this you should run a check of your drive account see if the file exits if it does delete it then upload your new version.   The only drawback to this would be if the file fails to upload then you will no longer have the original one unless you move the original one to trash then you could untrash it if the upload failed.

Comment: Thx,

I try to delete and create file but it s change the share link and I would like to keep that. ( A colleague needs this link) On the web-gui when I upload the new version, everything is ok.

I try to change the mind of my colleague.

Comment: It will because your uploading a new file.  Try getting the meta data of the original file.  And when you preform the upload use that metadata.  You need to try and upload with the same file id as the original file.   I havent tried this in a really long time.